# SQL LIKE statement not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in a table containing gene names. Example of gene names are dnaA, BN_001,BN_0023 etc...

I want to have all genes names that do not contain the underscore. The statement I used was this:

```
    SELECT Gene from cds WHERE Gene NOT LIKE '%_%';
```

However, this does not return the correct names of genes. What is the problem? I am using MYSQL as RDBMS.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `_` is a placeholder in ther `like` statement of any single character.

Instead you can use

```
SELECT Gene from cds 
WHERE instr(Gene, '_') = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You should write

```
LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

because _ mean something in SQL, so you have to escape this by \

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Gene from cds WHERE Gene NOT LIKE '%\_%';
```

Answer (score 1):

`_` is special character for `LIKE` operator. You must escape it, please try `Gene NOT LIKE '%\_%';`

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the underscore represents any single character in the `like` pattern.  You can read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) on this, but here is the relevant part:

> > With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern.

```
Character   Description
%   Matches any number of characters, even zero characters
_   Matches exactly one character
```

For this, just use a function like `locate()`:

```
where locate('_', gene) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the underscore, MySQL seems to support Standard SQL's `ESCAPE`

```
SELECT Gene from cds WHERE Gene NOT LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this `'%\_%'`

```
SELECT Gene from cds WHERE Gene NOT LIKE '%\_%';
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd685/2)